# How to change a stored procedure in VBA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, insert

first I have to say: My VB and SQL is limited to the absolute basics. I'm still studying and don't really have a real idea how working with databases works in VB (or in general).

My current task for work is: I've been given a 10 year old program, coded by an ex-employee. This program is written and based on visual studio (a lot of windows forms) and is basically just a database management tool. It's supposed to show the stored data sets and give the user the option to import excel files and add data manually. The program worked pretty good so far, but some of the dropdown menus do not write the selected value into the database, but instead just leave the field empty. I'm supposed to fix that.

Now at first I thought it'd be really easy. Just look at the code of the save-button and check if the insert command contains the correct names of the database fields. After a bit of searching (the code is uncommented and basically a mess) I've found the function that gets called when the save button is clicked. This function takes an SqlDataAdapter and calls the method "InsertCommand" with a stored procedure and the database connection as parameters. Then it adds the different parameters and executes the procedure.

My problem is: Where can I find the stored procedure and how do I change it? I'm guessing there's simply a typo in there for the dropdown fields or something, but since I can't see it and actually don't really have a clue what a stored procedure is, I don't know how to proceed.

Sadly I'm not allowed to post the code, but I hope my explanations are enough for you guys to understand my problem. I don't want you to fix my problem, but rather point me in the right direction - am I completely wrong here, or is my route a good guess?

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: None. We have hundreds of different databases but usually I don't work with them. I had to work with one about a year ago, back then I used Toad for MySQL, but I currently don't use one.

Comment: This is just too confusing... Are you really having problems writing SQL code for a non-existing database?

Comment: The database exists, but I never had access to it! As I said, my knowledge about database systems is nearly zero. I assumed that dbms stands for database management system and thought you can use whichever one you like to connect to a database - so since I haven't accessed the database yet, I don't use any dbms. The database exists and I'm not writing SQL code myself, I just want to check the existing code for errors.

Comment: DBMS stands for database management system. Popular dbms products include MS SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 and many others. Which one are you using?

Comment: I don't know! I think it's an SQL database, but the tool we're using to add/handle data in the database is not a public one, but an internal one, created specifically for this database.

Comment: SQL is a language, specified by ISO/ANSI. You probably mean Microsoft SQL Server, one of many products implementing SQL.

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry for the confusion, as I said I have no clue about databases. I know some basic SQL but the "technology" behind is still a mystery to me. It seems to be a Microsoft SQL Server, since I was able to use SSMS to connect to the database. Question for next time: Is it possible for me to find out what kind of database it is? The only thing I had was the code, otherwise I had no information and the other people in my department aren't IT people and have no clue about any IT-Stuff whatsoever (less than me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stored Procedure will be in the Database. 
Assuming its an MS-SQL database, open Sql Server management studio, find the database, and look under the "Programmability" folder - you should see the stored proc in there.

Comment: I'll try and see if I can get access to the database. Sadly I don't have any login data and the person responsible for our databases is gone for another 6 weeks. I'm pretty sure it's an SQL database.

Comment: You could be lucky, the login details may be in the code... or its using Windows authentication in which case you might be able to connect as yourself.

Comment: I've found the ip address of the workstation the database is running on in the code, aswell as username+password. I'll give it a try after lunch. We have windows authentication aswell, but I don't have rights to access the workstation. Thanks already!

Comment: chances are that the login details you found in the code will have all the permissions you need. From experience, security is seldom considered when users create their own Excel sheets that connect to databases.

Comment: It works! I can connect with SQL Server Management Studio with the login details I found! :) I found the procedures aswell, sadly there's no typo so the error must be somewhere else, but I'll have to search it myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.. Feel free to vote me up :)